# is this exotic resolution Dell U2913WM display supported?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display

I'm considering to upgrade to this [Dell U2913WM display](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&cs=04&l=en&s=bsd&sku=225-4201&baynote_bnrank=0&baynote_irrank=0&~ck=baynoteSearch&redirect=1) and was wondering whether it will work with Ubuntu given its exotic resolution of 2560 x 1080. My graphic card is nVidia GTX Titan so I have no compromises on this side.

If anyone has used it for development in Ubuntu I will be happy to know opinions.

Comment: I have the LG34UM95-P (3440x1440) with a 780 Ti and it works flawlessly with the proprietary drivers, I don't know about the open source drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only limit to your resolution is your hardware, so yes, your resolution will be supported as long as your GPU and monitor are capable of displaying it.

Comment: I don't think he is wondering about his hardware, more likely drivers.